# Hide user groups in user page odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I need to hide some Category/Groups in user(res.users) page. Like, if 'Technical Feature' is checked then the category 'Technical Settings' will display with all groups. If not checked the category will be invisible. I made lots of search but didn't find any useful solution. How can i do it? Please suggest any solution.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
attrs="{'invisible':[('technical_features_field','=',False)]}"
```

as an attribute in the group of the form view and also the separator of the form view. The technical settings group is actually inherited view. So check inherited view in edit form view section.

Thanks